# How do I find all occurrences of a sequence of chars when preceded by a specific string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to extract all matches from a EBML definition, which is something like this:

```
| + A track
|  + Track number: 3
|  + Track UID: 724222477
|  + Track type: subtitles
...
|  + Language: eng
...
| + A track
|  + Track number: 4
|  + Track UID: 745646561
|  + Track type: subtitles
...
|  + Language: jpn
...
```

I want all occurrences of "Language: ???" when preceded by "Track type: subtitles". I tried several variations of this:

```
Track type: subtitles.*Language: (\w\w\w)
```

I'm using the multi-line modifier in Ruby so it matches newlines (like the 's' modifier in other languages).

This works to get the **last** occurrence, which in the example above, would be 'jpn', for example:

```
string.scan(/Track type: subtitles.*Language: (\w\w\w)/m)
=> [["jpn"]]
```

The result I'd like:

```
=> [["eng"], ["jpn"]]
```

What would be a correct regex to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make your regex non-greedy by changing this:

```
.*
```

To this:

```
.*?
```

Your regex is matching from the first occurence of `Track type: subtitles` to the last occurence of `Language: (\w\w\w)`. Making it non-greedy will work because it matches as few characters as possible.

Comment: To Jeremy:
wait....you're 16 and understand 'geedyness'?!....and 8 Nice Answer badges?!!!...dang!...whatever job you're doing you're not getting paid enough....start offshore/nearshore codeing...like yesterday!  you'll make a tonne of cash before you're even out of school.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a lazy quantifier instead of `.*`. Try this:

```
/Track type: subtitles.*?Language: (\w\w\w)/m
```

This should get you the first occurrence of "`Language: ???`" after each "`Track type: subtitles:`". But it would get confused if some track (of type `subtitles`) would be missing the `Language` field.

---

Another way to do this would be:

```
/^\| \+ (?:(?!^\| \+).)*?\+  Track type: subtitles$(?:(?!^\| \+).)*?^\|  \+ Language: (\w+)$/m
```

Looks somewhat messy, but should take care of the problem with the previous one.

---

A cleaner way would be to tokenize the string:

```
/^\| \+ ([^\r\n]+)|^\|  \+ Track type: (subtitles)|^\|  \+ Language: (\w+)/m
```

*(Take note of the number of spaces)*

For each match, you check which of the capture groups that are defined. Only one group will have any value for any single match.

- If it is the **first** group, a new track has started. Discard any stored information about the previous track.
- If it is the **second** group, the current track is of type `subtitles`.
- If it is the **third** group, the language of this track is found.
- Whenever you know the language of a track, and that it is of type `subtitles`, report it.